# VHDL Coding .. conversion from integer to bit_vector

Tags: vhdl

I'm facing this problem , i'm asked to implement a function in VHDL that takes an integer and returns a bit_vector , assumed that this integer is represented by 4 bits.

i don't want to use already built in function, i have to code the function.

I have made a function to convert from bit_vector to integer which was kinda of easy, but im stuck here :S

Any ideas how can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VHDL standard packages is good inspiration for home brewed functions, and the `numeric_bit` package defines the `to_unsigned` function for conversion of `natural` type to `unsigned` type, which is the function VHDL actually uses for conversion to `bit_vector`.  The function is implemented as:

```
function TO_UNSIGNED (ARG, SIZE: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED is
  variable RESULT: UNSIGNED(SIZE-1 downto 0);
  variable I_VAL: NATURAL := ARG;
begin
  if (SIZE < 1) then return NAU;
  end if;
  for I in 0 to RESULT'LEFT loop
    if (I_VAL mod 2) = 0 then
      RESULT(I) := '0';
    else 
      RESULT(I) := '1';
    end if;
    I_VAL := I_VAL/2;
  end loop;
  if not(I_VAL =0) then
    assert NO_WARNING
        report "NUMERIC_BIT.TO_UNSIGNED: vector truncated"
        severity WARNING;
  end if;
  return RESULT;
end TO_UNSIGNED;
```

The initial `if (SIZE < 1)` and final `if not(I_VAL =0)` checks may be removed, if it is known that the function is never used with values that makes the checks relevant.

This leaves the `for I in 0 to RESULT'LEFT loop` that creates one result bit per iteration.

Based on Brian's answer, the constant LUT can be initialized using the `TO_UNSIGNED` function, to avoid the hand written literals:

```
function to_bv(n, size : natural) return bit_vector is

  type bv_arr_t is array (0 to 2 ** size - 1) of bit_vector(size - 1 downto 0);

  function bv_arr_init(size : natural) return bv_arr_t is
    variable res_v : bv_arr_t;
  begin
    for i in 0 to 2 ** size - 1 loop
      res_v(i) := bit_vector(TO_UNSIGNED(i, size));
    end loop;
    return res_v;
  end function;

  constant LUT : bv_arr_t := bv_arr_init(size);

begin
  return LUT(n);
end to_bv;
```

Comment: your answer did helped me a lot , thanks a lot mate , but can you tell me how exactly did you get this code from the ise library >?

Comment: Initialising LUTs from a function is a very useful technique too. My point was that in this case the explicit literals are probably simpler and less work!

Comment: @MSherin: Source files for packages can be found in [VHDL Supplemental Material](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076.2-1996/)

Answer (score 4):

Morten's is the correct answer but it's sometimes worth being open to alternative approaches...

As the question relates to a small (4-bit) range, a lookup table becomes attractive : I have assumed unsigned integers but it's easy to adapt.

```
subtype bv4 is bit_vector(3 downto 0);
constant LUT : array(0 to 15) of bv4 := (
   "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100, "0101", "0110", "0111",
   "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100, "1101", "1110", "1111");

function to_bv(n : natural) return bit_vector is
begin
   return LUT(n);
end to_bv;
```

This will normally synthesise as you would hope rather than actually creating a ROM!

Comment: yes this one is correct to i tried it , but it is not very useful  when it comes to higher than 4 bits , but thanks for the effort mate :)